# How to separate particular items in rows by class and if there is an item with a different class, append in a new row

Tags: jquery, wordpress

The title explained most of it, I've got a 4 columns row at the moment with several elements in it. The elements either have the classname no-media or has-media. They are all in the same row but I'd like to separate them with a row for the specific classes.

Now it looks like this:

```
<div class="body-content">
 <div class="items-wrapper">
  <div class="item has-media"> 
  <div class="item has-media">
  <div class="item has-media">
  <div class="item no-media">
  <div class="item no-media">
 </div>
</div>
```

What I'd like to achieve is this:

```
<div class="body-content">
 <div class="items-wrapper">

  <div class="item has-media"> 
  <div class="item has-media">
  <div class="item has-media">

 </div>

 <div class="items-wrapper">

  <div class="item no-media">
  <div class="item no-media">

 </div>
</div>
```

And as this is made with Wordpress I was thinking to do this with jQuery.. but I'm not quite sure if this is possible.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Question Do's and Don'ts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527), and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var items = new Array();
    $.each($('.body-content .no-media'), function( index, value ) {
      items.push(value);
      value.remove();
    });

    $('.body-content').append('<div class="items-wrapper new">');
    $.each(items, function( index, value ) {
      $('.new').append(value)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body-content">
 <div class="items-wrapper">
 <div class="item no-media">a No media</div>
  <div class="item no-media">b No media</div>
  <div class="item has-media"> a has-media</div>
  <div class="item has-media">b has-media</div>
  <div class="item has-media">c has-media</div> 
 </div>
</div>
```